# Extra members appearing in work details section of TFS backLog

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, backlog

I have a project on TFS. Team is divided into two Teams(eg. TeamA , TeamB) both Teams have separate working areas defined.

When I click on current iteration in backlog and select TeamA from the top of the page (MyProject/TeamA). All looks good. All work Items showing are Assigned to TeamA members and only TeamA members are appearing in work details area. (On left side)

Now when I select TeamB from the top of the page (MyProject/TeamB). All the members of TeamB are showing but also some members (not all) of TeamB are also showing in backlog. And these members are shown in Work details area section as well. however, only teamB members are shown in capacity section of sprint.

What I want is if I select TeamA from top only works items assigned to this specific team members and specific area path should appear. I want whole different backlog for both teams.

What I have tried. I checked perditions of all members and made sure sigle member are not appearing in  multi teams.

What am I missing?

Comment: In Team B's Sprint backlog (PBIs/Bugs) are any of their child Task Work Items assigned to members of Team A?

Comment: yes, that's my problem. if Some item is assigned to **Team A** members. it should be shown in **A** backlog only. It depends of team and area path? or from which backlog it is assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed by selecting default area path for TeamB in Area tab of settings page.

Default area for TeamA was already selected. so, it was not creating problem with TeamA.

But for TeamB default area was not set.

Comment: Your question stated "Both Teams have separate working areas defined" - they must have shared an area path which means a story in that area would appear on both backlogs.  Team B must have had 2 or more area paths selected (likely the root and somewhere else).  Setting the default simply means that any stories created by Team B will default to that area path.

Comment: **rerwin** your are right. Root Area path was selected for TeamB. So, user stories assigned to TeamA were showing in teamB. As TeamA area path was coming under root.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share Product Backlog Items/User Stories across teams like that.

If you pull in a story to Team B's sprint then all child tasks will appear on the board regardless of who they are assigned to because they belong to a story in Team B's sprint.

If the task is being completed by someone who is not in Team B perhaps a floating DBA or something then you could assign them some capacity in each of the teams and they'll have to duck in and grab Tasks from each of the teams.

Another way is to split the story smaller so one goes to Team A and the other to Team B.

You might also look at the structure of your teams.  Perhaps some reorginisation can make them more cross-functional and minimise this kind of problem.

Comment: I agree with you in this. But problem here is I am creating user story for team A (selecting **project/teamA** from top of **work** page). but it appears in backlog of teamB also. (not all user stories but some of them)